# Recursion for evaluating log(1+x) using taylor series of the same

Tags: c++, recursion, logarithm

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
double log(double x,int n)
{
    static double p = x ;
    double s;
    if(n==1)
        return x;
    else
    {
        s=log(x,n-1);
        p*=x;
        if(n%2==0)
            return s - (p/n);
        else
            return s + (p/n);  
    }
}
int main()
{
    double r = log(1,15);
    cout << r;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried writing the above function for evaluating the log(1+x) function using its taylor series with recursion. But it didn't gave the result as I expected.
Eg :
**ln(2) =  0.693** whereas my code gave **0.725**. In the above code, *n* represents the number of terms.
Also I am new to this platform, so can I say that the above question is complete or does it need some additional information for further explanation?

Comment: As an aside: If you mix operators in a single term as you do in `n%2==0` it is a good and reader-friendly idea to use brackets. Operator priorities are a common pitfall. Brackets help avoiding it. `(n%2)==0` is what makes the purpose more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely keep that in mind while writing other programs!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that piece of code: this has obviously got to do with the rate of convergence of the Taylor series.

If you take `n = 200` instead of `n = 15` in your code, the approximation error will be low enough that the first two decimals of the exact solution `ln(2) = 0.693147...` will be the correct ones.

The more you increase the `n` parameter, the better approximation you will get of `ln(2)`.

Comment: "The more you increase n..." if you increase it high enough, you get a stack overflow :)

Comment: @BitTickler: it would be interesting to check at which point you'd get this site's namesake, after all the recurring stack here is minimal

Answer (score 0):

Your program does converge to the right number, just very slowly...

`log(1,15)` returns 0.725, as you noticed, `log(1,50)` is 0.683, `log(1,100)` is 0.688, and `log(1,200)` is 0.691. That's getting close to the number you expected, but still a long way to go...

So there is no C++ or recursion bug in your *code* - you just need to find a better Taylor series to calculate log(X). Don't look for a Taylor series for log(1+x) - these will typically assume x is small, and converge quickly for small x, not for x=1.

Comment: Glad to know that!